# How to remove outlook vsto CustomTaskPane task pane option

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, outlook, vsto

How to remove outlook vsto CustomTaskPane task pane option
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trnyW.png)
I tried a variety of ways on the Internet (including Windows API, Windows handle) to delete this button, it seems not.And I found some blogs on stackoverflow that said they couldn't be deleted unless it was possible to use WebAddIn.
Please help me, everyone. Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.